# Trying to sort a linked HashMap <Character, Integer> by value

Tags: java, sorting, linkedhashmap

```
letterFrequencies.entrySet().stream()
        .sorted(Map.Entry.comparingByValue().reversed())
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(Entry::getKey, Entry::getValue));
```

I'm currently using this to try but I get an error which says `The method sorted(Comparator<? super Map.Entry<Character,Integer>>) in the type Stream<Map.Entry<Character,Integer>> is not applicable for the arguments (Comparator<Map.Entry<Object,Comparable<? super Comparable<? super V>>>>)`

Comment: `Collectors.toMap` - oops. Even if you get your `Comparator` to work, dumping the result into a `HashMap` isn't going to yield anything useful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try something like:

```
LinkedHashMap<Character, Integer> resultSet = 
                   letterFrequencies.entrySet().stream()
                  .sorted(Map.Entry.<Character, Integer>comparingByValue().reversed())
                  .collect(Collectors.toMap(Entry::getKey, Entry::getValue, (e1, e2) -> e1, LinkedHashMap::new));
```

Also, as mentioned by Boris the Spider, dumping the result into a `HashMap` will not maintain insertion order hence the use of `LinkedHashMap` here.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the `Comparator.reverseOrder()` like this and collect into *LinkedHashMap*

```
letterFrequencies.entrySet().stream()
            .sorted(Map.Entry.comparingByValue(Comparator.reverseOrder()))
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue,
                    (v1, v2) -> v1, LinkedHashMap::new));
```

Comment: You might want to change `comparingByKey` to `comparingByValue`